# Need good implementation for consuming multiple APIs with same output format but different properties

Tags: c#, api, rest, architecture

I'm working with multiple RESTFul APIs which returns data in following structure:

```
{
"total": 4,
"offset": 0,
"limit": 50,
**"data"**: [
          {
            "record_date": "2015-06-19 14:20:08",
            "user_id": "kdave@abc.com",
            "notes": "testing",
            "id": 25,
            "type": 1002
          },....
        ]
}
```

The "**data**" properties changes with different APIs. Currently, I need to create different classes "Data" under different namespace for deserializing the API output.

Any suggestions for handling this scenario in architecturally better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect problem for [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx):

```
public class RestResponse<TData>
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public TData[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then just define your various Data classes.

EDIT:

If your want to use the same deserialisation code consider using a generic method:

```
public RestResponse<T> DeserializeResponse<T>(...)
{
     var result = new RestResponse<T>();
     ...
     return result;
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
object result;
switch (...)
{
    case A:
        result = DeserializeResponse<ApiDataModelA>(...);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
}
```

Comment: A follow up question. Now I have the Class with generic type List. But I need to instantiate the object and based on certain value determine the concrete type for the List. I tried following but I guess this is not the right approach:  
`var genericRestTypeObj = typeof(RestResponse<>);

switch(concreteTypeVal)
{ case "1": {Type restObjType = typeof(apiModel); Type makeRestType = genericLogTypeObj.MakeGenericType(restObjType); var restObj = Activator.CreateInstance(makeRestType); genericRestTypeObj = restObj as GiTSLogApiOutputModel<SpecificApiModel>;    break; }
case "2": {.....}
}`

Comment: Please pardon my indentation due to character limit in comment.

Comment: `new RestResponse<apiModel>()` is what I'm doing currently. But I am writing boiler plate code for each case. I'm reading the API output and deserializing in each switch case. Instead I could be instantiating the Generic object before switch case and then determine the type based on respective case.  
Again, currently things are working perfectly fine but I intend to remove repetitive code.